# NSData object in iPhone

Tags: iphone

```
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/InAppLibrary"];

NSString *str=[@"/" stringByAppendingFormat:appDelegate_iPad.DrawPicture];
NSString *currentImageName=[imagePath  stringByAppendingFormat:str];

NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:currentImageName];
```

Here NSData object dataImage provide me null value, plz any buddy help me about what is wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is wrong, you should use:

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
  NSString *docPath =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  NSString *imagePath = [docPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/InAppLibrary/%@", appDelegate_iPad.DrawPicture];
  NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: imagePath ];
```

Comment: if my answer is correct please accept: Step by step guide "how does accepting an answer work" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235